# List of tuples to list of nested tuples, Non-exhaustive patterns in function Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am having difficulties with this.
I have tried to cover all the possible cases as I have read the similar questions here on stackOverFlow. But it's not working for me. Have tried multiple combinations.

```
convert :: ([(Int, Int)], String) -> [((Int, Int), String)]
convert (x, y) = zip (repeat y) x
convert ([] , y) = []
convert () = []
```

Comment: What goes wrong, exactly? If a compiler error, include it, and describe for us which parts you understand and which you struggle with. If a runtime error, include a minimal reproducing input. As it stands, the error in your question title and the errors in your code snippet do not match each other, which makes me a little suspicious that something fishy is going wrong here beyond just the code you've included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. One-clause definition,

```
convert :: ([(Int, Int)], String) -> [((Int, Int), String)]
convert (xs, y) = zip xs (repeat y)
```

does the trick.

```
> convert ([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)], "0")
[((1,1),"0"), ((2,2),"0"), ((3,3),"0")]
```

There's no need to handle the empty `[]` case for `xs` ourselves -- `zip` already correctly handles it.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based solely on the signature:

try

```hs
convert :: ([(Int, Int)], String) -> [((Int, Int), String)]
convert (ts, txt) = [ (t,txt) | t <- ts ]
```

or if you want to use `map`

```hs
convert :: ([(Int, Int)], String) -> [((Int, Int), String)]
convert (ts, txt) = map (\t -> (t,txt)) ts
```

to explain this a bit more:

you have as input a tuple with the first component being a list (of tuples again but that shouldn't matter here) and a `String` for the second parameter.

the output should be a list of tuples where the first component looks like what was in the input-list-component and the second a string again.

So most based on the signature the code above should do the trick.

Now maybe you want to do something other with the `(Int,Int)` inside the list but without further examples/explanation I cannot really tell.